# Django initialization code?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have some initialization code that I would like Django to run once, when the site is created.

Would it be appropriate to hook this code into a syncdb signal?
If so, where would this signal go?
But won't think run the code several times if I syncdb multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use some deployment tool like [fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Comment: fabric is about running commands on a remote-server. It doesn't say where I should put the code in my Django site.

Comment: You can place it in `bin/initial_setup.py`. And run this script from fabfile. Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: Well, I agree with DrTyrsa. Your requirements seems to be deployment-related, and therefore you should consider including it in a deployment-script.